# How to make a collection in c#?

Tags: c#, php

I have an associative array in PHP

```
$data=array(
    100=>array(
        "first"=>array(4,24,5,0),
        "second"=>array(42,58,23,8),
        "third"=>array(4,1,14,0),
        "fourth"=>array(49,41,28,2),
        "fifth"=>array(41,30,13,5)
    ),
    500=>array(
        "first"=>array(4,24,5,0),
        "second"=>array(42,58,23,8),
        "third"=>array(4,1,14,0),
        "fourth"=>array(49,41,28,2),
        "fifth"=>array(41,30,13,5)
    )
);
```

and i want to move that code into c# programming, but i don't know how to move it. I try to use List but i just can take in 100 and 500 only.
How to move it into c# programming?

Comment: You have made right choice by using `List`, what is the problem in the implementation which you encountered?

Comment: Please show what you actually tried in `c#`

Comment: @Ian A `List` is not an associative array, so what makes you think that it's appropriate at all?

Comment: @Servy I should rather say, `List` is okay, I think... perhaps `right` is quite strong word (could be for lacking of better understanding). But my reasoning is because the data set is small, `List` is easy to process, and you can put KVP in the `List` if be needed as well. Perhaps there is better/more efficient choice which is beyond my knowledge. But for the given case, I would say `List` is acceptable.

Comment: Consider creating classes that represent the concepts that you are trying to model using the arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

So you can do something like this:

```
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int[]>>
        {
            {
                100, new Dictionary<string, int[]>
                {
                    {"first", new[] {4, 24, 5, 0}},
                    {"second", new[] {42, 58, 23, 8}}
                }
            },
            {
                200, new Dictionary<string, int[]>
                {
                    {"first", new[] {4, 24, 5, 0}},
                    {"second", new[] {42, 58, 23, 8}}
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: looks like the key to the outer dictionary is an integer, not a string.  And the value of the inner dictionary is an int array, not just one int.

Comment: It was just a sample..but I just updated with the right implementation

Comment: It's even better in C# 6 with the new dictionary initializers

Answer (score 3):

Lists and Dictionaries are the way to go.

First you should make sure you are using the Generic collections namespace:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

At the top of your file.

you can then create your Dictionary of Dictionary of List of integer like so:

```
var data = new Dictionary<int,Dictionary<string,List<int>>>() {
   {100, new Dictionary<string, List<int>>() {
      {"first", new List<int>() {4, 24, 5, 0}},
      {"second", new List<int>() {42, 58, 23, 8}} //TODO - add third, fourth etc.
   }},
   {500, new Dictionary<string, List<int>>() {
      {"first", new List<int>() {4, 24, 5, 0}},
      {"second", new List<int>() {42, 58, 23, 8}} //TODO - add third, fourth etc.
   }}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, List<int>>>();
```

associative array are known as `Dictionary` in c#

As a sidenote: This feels very unintuitive in C#: Wrapping multiple Lists/Dictionarys inside each other isn't the most elegant solution.

---

Depending on your requirements it might be a better approach to wrap this construct inside classes:

Could be something like this:

```
public class DataContainer {
  public int Index { get; set; }
  public DataValue MyValue { get; set; }
}

public class DataValue {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<int> IntegerValues { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could simply have a List of DataContainers: `var data = new List<DataContainer>();`

Answer (score 2):

Associative arrays of `PHP` map to the `Dictionary` class of `C#`. Numeric arrays map to the `List` class, or to the more straightforward `array` (e.g. int[], string[]).

One major difference between `C#` and `PHP` is the fact that `C#` is a `strongly typed` programming language, meaning you need to declare the type of the variable. You can then use the literal syntax to build the dictionary.

```
var data = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int[] > >()
{
    [100] = new Dictionary<string, int[] >() 
    {
        ["first"] = new int[] {4, 24, 5, 0},
        ["second"] = new int[] {42, 58, 23, 8}
        // the rest of the items
    }
    // the rest of the items
};
```

Note. Thanks @juharr for pointing out, the above syntax works from `C# 6`. For previous versions, a similar syntax can be used:

```
var data = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int[] > >()
{
    { 100, new Dictionary<string, int[] >()
        {
            {"first", new int[] {4, 24, 5, 0} },
            {"second", new int[] {42, 58, 23, 8} }
            // the rest of the items
        }
    }
    // the rest of the items
};
```

Comment: Should be noted that you need C# 6 for this style of dictionary initialization.

Comment: @juharr thanks for the notice, will update the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a Dictionary: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

This is my 1 to 1 mapping of what I think you posted (you can replace List by int[] as well):

*Note: I do see that your inner dictionaries are always identical which there's no point in having 2 inner dictionaries but like I said, it's a 1 to 1 mapping of what I see*

```
            var mainDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, List<int>>>();
            var firstInnerDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
            var secondInnerDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

            firstInnerDictionary.Add("first", new List<int>{4,24,5,0});
            mainDictionary.Add(100, firstInnerDictionary);

            secondInnerDictionary.Add("first", new List<int>{4,24,5,0});
            mainDictionary.Add(500, firstInnerDictionary);
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a `Dictionary` as this:

```
var data = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, List<int>>>;
data[100] =new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
data[100]["first"] = new List<int>();
data[100]["first"].AddRange(new [] {4, 24, 5, 0});
// etc...
```

There are dictionary and list initialisers to make the code more compact though.